# Using SVM to predict text with label

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, supervised-learning

I have data in a csv file in the following format

```
Name     Power   Money
Jon      Red     30
George   blue    20
Tom      Red     40
Bob      purple  10
```

I consider values like "jon", "red" and "30 as inputs. Each input as a label. For instance inputs [jon,george,tom,bob] have label "name". Inputs [red,blue,purple] have label "power". This is basically how I have training data. I have bunch of values that are each mapped to a label.

Now I want to use svm to train a model based on my training data to accurately identify given a new input what is its correct label. so for instance if the input provided is "444" , the model should be smart enough to categorize it as a "Money" label.

I have installed py and also installed [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/). I have completed the following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTeVOb8gaD4) as well. I am just not sure on how to prepare input data to train the model.

Also I am new to machine learning if i have said something that sounds wrong or odd please point it out as I will be happy to learn the correct.

Comment: As you explain, it might be better to just do a search for the category inside your data, rather than doing machine learning on it. Also what happens when same string is present in two or more categories? Like Violet which may be a color or a name both.

Comment: You should update your question. Right now it looks like you have 6 classes and its a simple hashmap lookup rather than an ML problem. Especially with no MWE, it's difficult to give you useful suggestions.

Comment: @VivekKumar Yes i see your point. I have edited the question , please tell me if that makes more sense.

Comment: @jonnybazookatone thank you for the valuable feedback i have updated question  and please tell me if that makes more sense or more details are required.

Comment: Still not convinced that this requires machine learning. Anyways please add samples of all possible columns before further commenting.

Comment: @VivekKumar look at my edited and also below posted 2nd example by jonny is kind of what i am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With how your current question is formulated, you are not dealing with a typical machine learning problem. Currently, you have column-wise data:

```
Name     Power   Money
Jon      Red     30
George   blue    20
Tom      Red     40
Bob      purple  10
```

If a user now inputs "Jon", you know it is going to be type "Name", by a simple hash-map look up, e.g.,:

```
hashmap["Jon"] -> "Name"
```

The main reason people are saying it is not a machine-learning problem is your "categorisation" or "prediction" is being defined by your column names. Machine learning problems, instead (**typically**), will be predicting some response variable. For example, imagine instead you had asked this:

```
Name     Power   Money  Bought_item
Jon      Red     30     yes
George   blue    20     no
Tom      Red     40     no
Bob      purple  10     yes
```

We could build a model to predict *Bought_item* using the features *Name*, *Power*, and *Money* using SVM.

Your problem would have to look more like:

```
Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Category
1.0      foo      bar      Name
3.1      bar      foo      Name
23.4     abc      def      Money
22.22    afb      dad      Power
223.1    dad      vxv      Money
```

You then use *Feature1*, *Feature2*, and *Feature3* to predict *Category*. At the moment your question does not give enough information for anyone to really understand what you need or what you have to reformulate it this way, or consider an unsupervised approach.

**Edit**:

So frame it this way:

```
Name     Power   Money   Label
Jon      Red     30      Foo
George   blue    20      Bar
Tom      Red     40      Foo
Bob      purple  10      Bar
```

OneHotEncode Name and Power, so you now have a variable for each name that can be 0/1.

Standardise Money so that it has a range between, approximately, -1/1.

LabelEncode your labels so that they are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on.

Use a One vs. All classifier, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I just edited my question based on your feedback. I believe this is a supervised learning problem since I will have some data with labels and I want to train a model to predict new data points based on previous learnings. Please let me know if you need me to clarify this further.

Comment: You are giving too little information for a broad scope problem. You have a single input feature, with 3 possible labels. You don't need an ML approach to know '444' is an integer, and thus it's Money. Same with Power, do you have a list of colours that always mean power? If so, you can do a simple hashmap of all possible colours to classify it as a colour.

Comment: I would definitely have much more than 3 labels while solving the problem. i just decided to stick with 3 for simplicity. The categories provided are simplified so i can focus on the step of preparing data for the svm model. IF this was my real problem then i agree hashmap is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for making the edit, It seems more clear now. so follow up question is when you say onehotencode name and power does that mean i can pass raw text or do i have to transform text before using onehotencode to generate variables

Comment: You could use something like this; https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: I am confused about how we are framing the problem. In my case  this is what I have input1[george,joe,jon,manny] label1: 'name' and then i can have input2[30,40,50,60,70,]label2: 'money'

Comment: From your edit it seems like name:jon,power:red,money:30 are all pointing to label foo. which is not the case. name is the label for jon, power is the label for value red and money is the label for value 30.